# Проверить, входит ли слово в ссылку, и нет ли ее в атрибутах

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
<a href="/href/blabla">внедорожники 1</a> какие-то такие, но не всегда 
внедорожники 2 бывают внедорожники 3 <img alt="всегда свежие внедорожники 4" 
title="сила - это внедорожники 5" /><a href="/href/blabla">какие-то такие 
внедорожники 6 но не всегда но не всегдано не всегдано не всегдано не 
всегдано не всегдано не всегдано не всегдано не всегдано не всегда</a>
```

Задача: нужно получить все вхождения, но те, которых нет в ссылке и нет в атрибутах (alt и title). Т.е. надо получить "внедорожники 2" и "внедорожники 3".

У меня есть такая регулярка:

```
\#внедорожники(?!.{0,1000}<\/a>)(?!.{0,1000}\/>)(?!.{0,1000}>)\#i
```

Но она работает некорректно, т.к. проверяется лишь окончание на /> или >, но не проверяется на начало. Если поставит цифру 1000, то начнет искать. Но только лишь потому, что закрывающие теги находятся за пределами 1000 символов.

Вопрос: как можно сконструировать выражение, чтобы проверялось на наличие открывающего тега?

Спасибо!

**UPD:** Диалект - PHP (pcre).
{0,1000} - я сделал для того, чтобы отладить этот процесс. Так сказать, опыты :) Мне пока главное чтобы работало.. :)

Comment: > .{0,1000} - оу оу оу, полегче.
UPD: сейчас подумаемс...

Comment: а какой диалект регулярок ? js, PCRE ?

Comment: Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Принципиально ли решить проблему одним регулярным выражением? Или можно воспользоваться несколькими? В последнем случае можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$text = strip_tags(preg_replace('/<[^>]+>[^<]+<[^>]+>/', '', $text));
preg_match_all('/внедорожники\s+\d+/is', $text, $out);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';
```